# Defining mongoose Model Methods Dynamically

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, dynamic, mongoose

I'm in the case of a function being able to search by different fields depending on the situation.

It returns the same dataset, it just searches by different fields: either userId or tagId. Therefore, in my code I have something like this:

```
var findByMethod;

if (searchBy === 'userId') {
    findByMethod = UserArticleModel.findByUser;
}

else {
    findByMethod = UserArticleModel.findByTag;
}

findByMethod(idToSearch, function (err, articles) {…});
```

`findByUser` and `findByTag` are static methods defined in the `UserArticleModel.js`

`UserArticleModel.js`

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var userArticleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        …
    }
});

userArticleSchema.statics.findByUser = function (userId, callback) {
    this.find({userId: userId}, function () {…});
};

userArticleSchema.statics.findByTag = function (tagId, callback) {…};

module.exports = mongoose.model('UserArticle', userArticleSchema);
```

Back in my controller, when I do:

```
UserArticleModel.findByTag(idToSearch, function (err, articles) {…});
```

All is well and things go right. But when I dynamically call the method via my variable:

```
findByMethod(idToSearch, function (err, articles) {…});
```

Things go wrong as node returns an error:

```
DOMAINE ERROR CAUGHT: TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'find'
```

I suspect `this` not to be be bound to the correct scope but I don't really understand why as `findByMethod === UserArticleModel.findByUser // true`

Comment: Well the problem is going to be in how you are implementing the code to establish these, which is also not the part you are showing. But as a basic principle, to set these up you shold basically be "cycling" the fields present in the schema and calling like: `userArticleSchema.statics[fieldName] = function(arg,callback) { var query = {}; query[fieldName] = arg; this.findOne(query,function(err,doc) { ...`.  etc. Where you should get the general gist. All JavaScript is just objects.

Comment: Unless it's a typo in the question then `userArticleSchema.staticsfindByTag` is your real "typo" problem as you forgot the dot "."

Comment: It was a typo in de question, I corrected it. thx

Comment: How about trying it my way as suggested. Very clean. But the first part should be `userArticleSchema.statics["findBy" + fieldName]` instead. My own "typo" I guess.

Comment: If I understand well, you suggest that I have a "dynamic static" in the schema?

Comment: Well yes and no. All the call using `schema.static` is doing is essentially "setting up" the "named objects" ( as that is all they really are ) within the schema defintiion. So where you can use the "bracket" notation `[]` "use it", as it is just interpolation of a variable into an "object key", which is how you set up the methods. Beyond the actual "naming" the method implementations are functionally basically the same, with the same "field name" interpolation. Get me? I can basically visualize the example, but coding it up for "completeness" takes a bit of effort. I might try.

Comment: But you could "try" as well, since the general mechanics are already explained. I suspect the "root" of the problems you have now are being over terse in definining these things separately and trying to link back a "common function" in the wrong kind of way.

Comment: All right, I finally got it working thanks to your advice. In my if/else block defining `findByMethod` variable; I replaced `findByMethod = UserArticleModel.findByUser;` by `findByMethod = 'findByUser';` and then call with `UserArticleModel[findByMethod](…`

Comment: I actually have something "better" in mind. Mind if I give it a shot as an answer? Won't take long to complete.

Comment: I absolutely get how bracket notation works and that it's possible to call dynamic properties and method thanks to variable interpolation but why doesn't it work if my `findByMethod` variable corresponds to the exact same thing. For instance if defined `findByMethod = 'findByUser';
        findByMethodComp = UserArticleModel.findByUser;` then console.log(UserArticleModel[findByMethod] === findByMethodComp); //true`

Comment: Of course I don't mind. I'll be glad to see a different (and better) approach!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are making this more involved that it need be. Though it is an easy trap to fall into by "too literally" following documented API examples and thinking essentially *"this is how I need to hardcode this, because the docs say this is how you do it"*.

JavaScript objects are, well "Objects", and therefore just assigning "named" static methods which are really only object properties is just a basic process of "looping" the defined "schema paths" from that already defined "Object" and setting up the properties for the "findByFieldName" methods you want.

It's just "assigning named properties" and nothing more obscure or complex or even as "terse" than that.

If that *"sounds like a mouthful"* then the actual process of iterating object properties and "setting other properties" related to that within an overall object structure is not really as hard as you might think.

As a brief example:

```
var async = require('async'),
    pascal = require('to-pascal-case'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var testSchema = new Schema({
  fieldA: String,
  fieldB: Number
});

function setStatics(schema) {
  Object.keys(schema.paths).filter(function(key) {
    return key != '_id';
  }).forEach(function(key) {
    schema.statics['findBy' + pascal(key)] = function(arg,callback) {
      var query = {};
      query[key] = arg;
      this.findOne(query,callback);
    };
  });
};

// Set up findByFieldName other than _id
setStatics(testSchema);

var Test = mongoose.model( 'Test', testSchema, "test" );

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

async.series(
  [
    function(callback) {
      Test.remove({},callback);
    },
    function(callback) {
      Test.create([
        { "fieldA": "a", "fieldB": 1 },
        { "fieldA": "b", "fieldB": 2 }
      ],callback);
    },
    function(callback) {
      Test.findByFieldA("a",function(err,doc) {
        console.log(doc);
        callback(err);
      });
    },
    function(callback) {
      Test.findByFieldB(2,function(err,doc) {
        console.log(doc);
        callback(err);
      });
    }
  ],
  function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    mongoose.disconnect();
  }
);
```

Which proves that they work by "testing them" with the output:

```
{ _id: 55f2ae1b7d8315f40b1a2b77, fieldA: 'a', fieldB: 1, __v: 0 }
{ _id: 55f2ae1b7d8315f40b1a2b78, fieldA: 'b', fieldB: 2, __v: 0 }
```

And that is all there is to it.

Of course for fields like "Arrays" you want to get a little more involved, but this is the basic premise as a listing you can try out yourself ( or selves for the community in general ).

I could also note that there are already a few things out there such as [Bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) via it's own `.promisifyAll()` call  which interacts with objects to set new up "named methods" on the object in a similar way. Or at least it should be similar in principle, as I have not actually looked at that code.

Comment: This is a really nice one! Thank you very much.

Comment: @Buzut As warned it is "overly simplified" for producion use in general, but it does illustrate the concepts. Already thinking if a bit of searching does not match anything similar then a bit of time might result in a published package that is a lot more complete. After all, I know things like "grails" set up methods like these by default. And at least it also prompted me to remove the close/hold vote due to an initial suspition this was basically typos. The "question" with all the insight in what you were trying to achieve is actually a useful one.

Comment: I took note that it's not production ready but it is inspiring! I'm sure a npn module would be really useful.